# Is it possible to encrypt persistence in metasploit?

Tags: exploit, metasploit

What I generally do, is I encrypt my payload with [`Veil-Evasion`](https://github.com/Veil-Framework/Veil-Evasion)

But then after I get the shell, I keep on migrating of course; But when I enter the 
command

`run persistence`

in the meterpreter shell, the vbs script generated is being detected by almost all anti-virus. Is there any way I could encrypt it ?

I would like to have longer time persistence

Answer (score 0):

Well, i'm not sure if that's possible or not.

But i think the reason that the persistence is detected by almost every antivirus, is caused by the heuristic analysis, so even if you encrypt the persistence ... it is possible it will be detected in any case.

Comment: @Hollowproc this answer pre-dates the closing of the question